# Chain differentiation of bilinear form.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, chain-rule, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

Suppose one has a bilinear form $\alpha(x,y)$ and suppose one has the derivative
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \alpha(x,ty)$$
How does the chain differentiation work in this case? Is it
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial (ty)} \alpha(x,ty) \frac{d}{dt}(ty)$$
or
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \alpha(x,ty) \frac{d}{dt}(ty)$$
As I understand it one should differentiate $\alpha$ with respect to the second argument so the first option is the correct one. But often I see the second option in books.

Answer (score 1):

The second version is correct; it is the definition of the chain rule.
Let's recap:

Let $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable functions and just for notation let $f(x)$ be a function in $x$ and $g(y)$ a function in $y$ (that is just to make clear what we are deriving for). Then
\begin{equation}
(f(g(y))' = f'(g(y))\cdot g'(y)
\end{equation}
or with another notation
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial }{\partial y} f(g(y)) = \frac{ \partial }{\partial y} \Big( (f \circ g) (y) \Big) = \frac{ \partial f }{\partial x} (g(y)) \cdot \frac{ \partial g }{\partial y} (y)
\end{equation}
The term
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial f }{\partial x}
\end{equation}
appears because you need to derive $f$ in respect to its coordinates and *after that* you apply it to $g(y)$.

So in your case the term
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \alpha (x, ty) 
\end{equation}
does not mean that you are deriving for the *number* $y$, it means you are derivating for the second coordinate - that is what you probably wanted to say with
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial (ty)} \alpha (x, ty).
\end{equation}

Comment: One might say the abbreviated notation of "partial derivative" leads into confusion here.  In asking for a partial derivative with respect to $t$, one needs to identify how $t$ varies while another variable (or more) remains fixed.  It is possible that the original context would shed light on whether partial wrt $t$ should have been a total derivative or even an ordinary derivative with respect to $t$.